# Label obj not working as expected

Tags: c#

I am trying to achieve a file lister, which will list all files in specified path. To do so I used mixture of panel, labels and File objects. The code to achieve this is as follow

```
            label_songlist[i].Text=filename[i];
            label_songlist[i].Height=25;
            label_songlist[i].Location=new Point(x,y);
            label_songlist[i].AutoSize=true;
            label_songlist[i].Font=new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif,10);
            label_songlist[i].BorderStyle=BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            label_songlist[i].Padding=new Padding(0,0,0,5); 
panel.Controls.Add(label_songlist[i]);
```

This works fine for first 5 file. After first five files it some how add space to left for remaining file giving output something like this

[image: Output image].

However, the value of x is never changed through out the execution of program. I did collect value of x and y for each label and wrote it  to file. After execution I checked file. The value of **X** is  **0**. No change at all.

Comment: Instead of going through all these mess, why wouldn't you use ListView

Comment: The gap seems to be as wide as the vertical scroll bar, does this also happen when you disable the scroll bars?

Comment: No it does not. So the problem is the scroll bar. How does it effects the output. Can anyone enplane it?